# Is it possible to mimic Go interface in C/C++?

Tags: go

In Go, if the type has all the methods that the interface defined then it can be assigned to that interface variable without explicitly inheriting from it.

Is it possible to mimic this feature in C/C++?

Comment: In some sense, that is what templates do. If you invoke a function with templatized arguments, you can pass in any objects which would meet the requirements as defined by how you use the template.

Comment: http://wall.org/~lewis/2012/07/23/go-style-interfaces-in-cpp.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. You can use a pure abstract class, and use a template class to wrap types "implementing" the abstract class so that they extend the abstract class. Here's a barebones example:

```
#include <iostream>

// Interface type used in function signatures.
class Iface {
public:
        virtual int method() const = 0;
};

// Template wrapper for types implementing Iface
template <typename T>
class IfaceT: public Iface {
public:
        explicit IfaceT(T const t):_t(t) {}
        virtual int method() const { return _t.method(); }

private:
        T const _t;
};

// Type implementing Iface
class Impl {
public:
        Impl(int x): _x(x) {}
        int method() const { return _x; }

private:
        int _x;
};


// Method accepting Iface parameter
void printIface(Iface const &i) {
        std::cout << i.method() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
        printIface(IfaceT<Impl>(5));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course.

In fact the code that handles interfaces in the runtime is written in C. 
http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/runtime/iface.c

Answer (score 3):

In C++20 there are ***`conceps`***, they seems quite bit like go interfaces

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints

```
// Given the following data types
struct Type1 {
    bool m(int i) {
        return i > 0;
    }
};

struct Type2 {
    bool m(int i, int defaultArg = 0) {
        return (i % 2) == defaultArg;
    }
};

#include <iostream>
#include <string>


// I declare this concept
template<typename T>
concept HasUsefulMethod = requires(T a, int b) {
    { a.m(b) } -> std::same_as<bool>;
};


// So I can declare the following function that can take
// all classes that implement an m(int) -> bool
std::string calculateResult(HasUsefulMethod auto x, int i = 0){
    return std::string {
        x.m(i) ? "yes" : "no"
    } + "!";
}



int main()
{
    std::cout << "calculate result for struct Type1: " << calculateResult(Type1{}, -1)  << std::endl;
    std::cout << "calculate result for struct Type2: " << calculateResult(Type2{})  << std::endl;
}
```

I'm necromancing this post because I think that C++'s `concept`s are a very useful functionality

#### Edit

it seems to work even with default parameters, see `Type2::m`

https://wandbox.org/permlink/gvlr0nFi56El8vcu

Comment: Is calculateResult() implicitly a function template?

Comment: I'm not sure how it is implemented in compilers but I think yes, it should be a template, because it has `auto` in the type of the argument `x`, with the `HasUsefulMethod` constraint

Answer (score 0):

I guess some rough equivalence might be feasible with [GObject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GObject).

Answer (score 0):

I took a stab at it for C++.  I ended up with something that works, but is a macro circus:  https://github.com/wkaras/c-plus-plus-misc/tree/master/IFACE .  An interface is two pointers, one to object data members, and another to the equivalent of a virtual table (a structure of pointers to thunk functions that call member functions).  These tables are (unfortunately) generated at run-time.  Conversion from an interface to a sub-interface requires an unordered_map look up, so it's O(1) time complexity on average.  As compared with converting a derived class pointer/reference to one to a base class, which is O(1) worst-case.

It's not very usable, but it does show that interfaces could be (cleanly) added to C++ with relatively little effort.  There are cases where interfaces are better than inheritance-based OO, and the cow is well out of the barn as far as trying to keep C++ small.